# SBT builder crashed with error message "null"

Tags: scala, sbt

My setup:

Ubuntu 12.04

Java 1.6.0_45

Eclipse 3.7.2

Scala IDE 2.0.0.v-2_08-201112200107-82421c5

Situation: I tried to run the source code of Kafka, which is wrote in Scala, and with java files. after the import(there seems no error), the problem view shows like this:

Error Description:
The SBT builder crashed while compiling your project. This is a bug in the Scala compiler or SBT. Check the Erorr Log for details. The error message is: null

Stack trace:

```
!ENTRY org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4 4 2013-06-18 10:03:48.583
!MESSAGE Error during askOption
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$addDefaultGetters$2$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Namers.scala:1043)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$addDefaultGetters$2$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Namers.scala:968)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:61)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$addDefaultGetters$2.apply(Namers.scala:968)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$addDefaultGetters$2.apply(Namers.scala:965)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:123)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:45)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:139)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.$div$colon(List.scala:45)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.addDefaultGetters(Namers.scala:965)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.methodSig(Namers.scala:918)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.typeSig(Namers.scala:1165)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$typeCompleter$1.apply(Namers.scala:545)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$typeCompleter$1.apply(Namers.scala:543)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$$anon$1.complete(Namers.scala:1345)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$$anon$1.complete(Namers.scala:1341)
at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:747)
at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$Symbol.paramss(Symbols.scala:952)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$DefOwner$class.addDef(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:645)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$Builder.addDef(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:839)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$DefOwner$class.addDef(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:635)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$Builder.addDef(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:839)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$TreeTraverser.traverse(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:913)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$TreeTraverser$$anonfun$traverse$1.apply(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:920)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$TreeTraverser$$anonfun$traverse$1.apply(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:920)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:61)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$TreeTraverser.traverse(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:920)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$TreeTraverser$$anonfun$traverse$1.apply(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:920)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$TreeTraverser$$anonfun$traverse$1.apply(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:920)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:61)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$TreeTraverser.traverse(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:920)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$TreeTraverser$$anonfun$traverse$1.apply(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:920)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$TreeTraverser$$anonfun$traverse$1.apply(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:920)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:61)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser$TreeTraverser.traverse(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:920)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaStructureBuilder$StructureBuilderTraverser.traverse(ScalaStructureBuilder.scala:871)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaCompilationUnit$$anonfun$buildStructure$2$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaCompilationUnit.scala:77)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaCompilationUnit$$anonfun$buildStructure$2$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ScalaCompilationUnit.scala:76)
at scala.tools.eclipse.javaelements.ScalaCompilationUnit$$anonfun$buildStructure$2$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ScalaCompilationUnit.scala:76)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.InterruptReq.liftedTree1$1(InterruptReq.scala:20)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.InterruptReq.execute(InterruptReq.scala:19)
at scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global.pollForWork(Global.scala:330)
at scala.tools.nsc.interactive.PresentationCompilerThread.run(PresentationCompilerThread.scala:22)

!ENTRY org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4 4 2013-06-18 10:04:27.824
!MESSAGE Crash in the build compiler.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at scala.tools.nsc.settings.MutableSettings$OutputDirs$$anonfun$outputDirFor$1.apply(MutableSettings.scala:295)
at scala.tools.nsc.settings.MutableSettings$OutputDirs$$anonfun$outputDirFor$1.apply(MutableSettings.scala:295)
at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:53)
at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:52)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.find(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:102)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.find(List.scala:45)
at scala.tools.nsc.settings.MutableSettings$OutputDirs.outputDirFor(MutableSettings.scala:295)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenJVM$BytecodeGenerator.getFile(GenJVM.scala:1706)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenJVM$BytecodeGenerator.emitClass(GenJVM.scala:146)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenJVM$BytecodeGenerator.genClass(GenJVM.scala:269)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenJVM$JvmPhase.apply(GenJVM.scala:56)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenJVM$JvmPhase$$anonfun$run$3.apply(GenJVM.scala:52)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenJVM$JvmPhase$$anonfun$run$3.apply(GenJVM.scala:52)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(HashMap.scala:89)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(HashMap.scala:89)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:631)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:161)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:194)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2.foreach(HashMap.scala:89)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenJVM$JvmPhase.run(GenJVM.scala:52)
at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:761)
at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:842)
at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:106)
at scala.tools.eclipse.buildmanager.sbtintegration.ScalaSbtCompiler.compile(ScalaSbtCompiler.scala:35)
at scala.tools.eclipse.buildmanager.sbtintegration.AnalysisCompile$$anonfun$8.compileScala$1(AnalysisCompile.scala:124)
at scala.tools.eclipse.buildmanager.sbtintegration.AnalysisCompile$$anonfun$8.apply(AnalysisCompile.scala:162)
at scala.tools.eclipse.buildmanager.sbtintegration.AnalysisCompile$$anonfun$8.apply(AnalysisCompile.scala:99)
at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:21)
at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:19)
at sbt.inc.Incremental$.cycle(Incremental.scala:33)
at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:20)
at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:17)
at scala.tools.eclipse.buildmanager.sbtintegration.AnalysisCompile.doCompile(AnalysisCompile.scala:180)
at scala.tools.eclipse.buildmanager.sbtintegration.EclipseSbtBuildManager.runCompiler(EclipseSbtBuildManager.scala:360)
at scala.tools.eclipse.buildmanager.sbtintegration.EclipseSbtBuildManager.update(EclipseSbtBuildManager.scala:327)
at scala.tools.eclipse.buildmanager.sbtintegration.EclipseSbtBuildManager.build(EclipseSbtBuildManager.scala:389)
at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaProject.build(ScalaProject.scala:697)
at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaBuilder.build(ScalaBuilder.scala:107)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: I hate to say this but keep compiling. Sometimes the type checker just runs out of stack.

Comment: I changed workspace, compiled again, but without change, the error message is still null...

Answer (score 0):

One reason this may be happening is that your classpath is incomplete. Make sure all binaries needed by Kafka are in the Build classpath of your Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Scala 2.11.8 and had a similar error. I had in my code a variable named `carrotPosition` that didn't exist and should have been named `carrot.position`. The compiler didn't point out that this variable didn't exist and instead just crashed. Specifically I used the variable to index into an `ArrayBuffer` using `carrotPosition - 1`. It turns out that I could put any variable name there and the compiler would crash. But the `-1` has to be there.